# Hide category name in URL

Tags: categories, url-rewriting

I have this situation myurl.com/catA leads to main wordpress site, and I need to make that myurl.com/catB should leads to specify wordpress category but without showing it in url like myurl.com/catA/specifycategory. Url should stay as myurl.com/catB.

Is it possible?

At this point I see only one solution at index in template base on given url I will display all or only one category.

Answer (score 0):

yes we can hide category by using plugin yoast seo
got to advanced of seo and in that go to permalinks mark up the 1st option 
Strip the category base (usually /category/) from the category URL "
and save 
its all done now

Comment: Ok this option is checked but name of the category is still showing.